# Can Boost be used as a full replacement of the C++ Standard library?

Tags: c++, boost, std

Say I have minimal headers like `<new>`, `<initializer_list>`, and maybe some other stuff, is it possible to use Boost to function as a std C++ library, or is there a lot of code missing?

I'm assuming a C standard library, which might have sucky versions of things like `printf` (think Windows), will Boost provide better implementations in `<boost/cstddef>` (or something)?

Comment: There's nothing "missing" from Boost, but Boost also doesn't strive to be a basic standard library...

Comment: Lot of standard library classes depend on indirect header includes so you will end up bringing in a lot of headers eventually.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You probably meant *short*? :)

Comment: @AlokSave it should also _sort_ the answers with "no", i.e. answers that say "no" should come first :)))

Comment: I'd be rather interested in why you ask that.

Comment: @Angew: for one, then I'd use everything from `boost::` instead of `std::`. Secondly, this would be a very cheap way to get a very decent standard library for free, e.g. to replace the somewhat lacking libstdc++ (if you dust off enough corners).

Comment: @rubenvb: *somewhat lacking libstdc++*? What is it lacking?

Comment: @AlokSave: Correct, I meant *short*, dropping the *h* made it even *sorter*.

Comment: It would have been too long if you'd left the `'h'` in.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas on Windows: decent `std::thread` (one not based on a pthreads emulation layer), `std::to_string`, a decent `std::printf`, `<regex>`...

Comment: @rubenvb: On the other side: `std::map<>`, `std::string`, ... Boost implements some of the libraries that have become part of the standard, but is is **not** a replacement. Additionally, I would expect `std::thread` in the VS implementation to be just as good as that of boost (although not portable). Also I seem to recall that there were slight semantic differences between the boost and the std threading libs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Boost is not designed to *replace* the C++ standard library; it is designed to *complement* and *extend* the C++ standard library. Also, Boost depends heavily on the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 4):

Well, no. For example, Boost doesn't define a stream encapsulating *standard out*. Sure, you can use `STDOUT` *itself* with some lower-level functions, but by that logic you can do pretty much everything without using the standard library at all.

Comment: Or you can encapsulate `STDOUT` using _Boost.IOStreams_, but that is built on the standard library as well...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Boost or any other truly cross platform libraries for anything that is even remotely likely to be platform dependent. Networking / locking etc.

For everything else, I would stick to the standard libraries - they're well documented, they're often optimized for the OS and with the exception of a few ifdefs you may need to endure here and there, they'll compile and run fine on most platforms.